# Ideal setup for 26kVA pull

Tags: electrical

Ideal electrical setup for  26 kVA minimum pull? I know 200 Amps isn't gonna cut it. I have fans and other stuff. Ideally, I'd like to drop them to 240 to maximize power efficiency. I'll be running 21 or 22 15Amp circuits off of the panel. Each unit will have a 1300 Watt pull, 21 or 22 units. I never was a lead electrician, but I did a lot of electrical work back in the day. Any help would be appreciated, much respect to all you other sparkies.

(I am in south us)

Norman

Comment: Are you asking about the total service for an occupancy or something added to an existing occupancy? A 120/240 volt 200 amp service will deliver 48 kVA. That would be plenty for 22 15-amp circuits if there is nothing you are not telling us about. What type of occupancy is it? I assume it is not residential. Do the 22 circuits cover all of the circuits required by code?

Comment: This doesn’t sound like a residential DIY project but it looks like EE migrated it to us.  You need it edit in the rest of the story tho, to be able to get a code compliant answer.

Comment: Trick being, 200A of 120V is not the same as 200A of 240V.  Sounds kinda obvious when you say it like that eh?

Comment: Also 22 - 1300watt@120v circuits in an evenly distributed panel are like 11 - 1300 watt 240v circuits.

Comment: Are these fans and lights for a greenhouse? Growing . . . ?

Comment: Careful with units @Tyson ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. Not for a greenhouse, they are for computers. It is being done in the rear of a residential property, however all of my experience rests in commercial electrical, mostly. That said, I've the skillset enough to do what I've done so far, which is branch out of my main panel to a subpanel in my shop with a 60 amp breaker, for three computers and extra power for other stuff.  On 120, it can run three of the computers, I believe on 240 it has the capability to run double that?